# Cached Data and $.get method

Tags: jquery, caching

I understand that `$.get` caches data and `$.post` does not. What I want to know is this:

Assume that I access some data using `$.get` and then create some variables or classes out of that data. If I then do something with those variables/classes (i.e. change something) will those changes remain in the cache?

For example, the next time the `$.get` function is called will those modified variables or classes still be there?

It would look something like this:

```
$.get('getsomedatafrommyql.php', function(data) {
  // create a load of variables or classes from data
  // do something with those vars or classes, modify some of them maybe.
})
```

The next time `function(data)` is called will all those vars and classes still be there in their modified state? Or do they get reverted back to what they initially were? Ideally, I want them to be in their modified state each time?
Also, is it important that at some point the cache should be cleared?

Comment: 1) `$.get caches data and $.post does not` - this is not the case. Both can cache data, depending on the setting used. 2) The data within the success callback is always what was received in the request. Any values you change in the response from one request will be ignored when the next one is received. 3) Note that what you're describing here is not what caching is, in the context of the request data.

Comment: Consider `$.get` a page in a book and `var` something you write in a notepad.  When you read the page in the book, it's the same (as it's cached) - but each time you write something down it's new because you're writing it new.  **edit** this sounded better in my head :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: But how do I work around asynchronous nature of $get ? I want to read a load of data and set a load of variables and classes and then use that later in my code. But you can only do that in the function data call, i think.